# How Can I Speed Up Loading Oracle Views into HDFS via Spark?

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql

In order to speed up our load for tables, we take the rowid, hash it, and partition over it. The code for it is below. However, views don't have rowid and without figuring out what column to partition over, we don't have a generic solution to ingesting in parallel. Is there a way to generically ingest views in parallel, without materializing the view?

```
spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", url)
    .option("user", username)
    .option("password", new String(decrypt(decodeBase64(encryptedPassword), key), "UTF-8"))
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    .option("dbtable", query)
    .option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
    .option("lowerBound", 0)
    .option("upperBound", numPartitions)
    .option("partitionColumn", s"mod(ora_hash(rowid),${numPartitions})+1")
    .option("oracle.net.networkCompression", "on")
    .option("SDU", OracleSDU)
    .option("fetchsize", FetchSize)
    .load()
```

Comment: First ideas: expose rowid from tables that are used in view or do some `row_number() over (order by rowid) as key`

Comment: Not in my view as tgere could be many joibs underlying